# How to tag children of a particular xml node using xmlutils in Python?

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am having a bit of trouble using xml2csv function.

Here is an example of the xml I am trying to convert to csv:

```
<resources>
       <resource>
           <id>1</id>
           <key>229</key>
           <msr>241223</msr>
      </resource>
  </resources>
```

Using xml2csv, I can only tag one item, for instance tag="msr". However, what if I would want to convert all child nodes of `<resource>`? Is there a better way than to just tag each field manually and then concatenating them to a single csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tag to resource - the documentation says that the tag should be the record level not each item of a record